# Отловить закрытие окна сохранения файлов в браузере

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, frontend, браузер

Как мне отловить событие закрытия окна сохранения файлов в браузере?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать такое решение:

```js
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    input.addEventListener('click',enter)
    function enter(){
        document.body.addEventListener('focusin',leave)
    }
    function leave(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            alert('Окно закрыто');
            document.body.removeEventListener('focusin',leave)
        },100)
    }
```

```html
<input type='file' id='input' />
```

Comment: у меня немного другая ситуация, я отправляю запрос на контроллер, он в ответ мне отдает объект `return File(zipStream, "application/x-zip-compressed", "Certificates.zip");` `zipStream` - это байтовый массив. В итоге уменя автоматом открывается окно..

Comment: @РоманТимохов Подскажите, почему хотите отследить тогда именно его закрытие? Теоретически оно же точно таким же образом теряет фокус с DOM?

Comment: Когда я отправляю запрос на контроллер, в браузере запускается блокирующий действия попап(ну такое затемнение с спинером в центре). Контролер активирует сервис, задача котрого скачатьть с внешнего сервака пдфы, заархивировать их и прислать пользователю для скачивания зип. Этот процесс занимает время(в это время на экране действует попап), а когда появляется окно скачивания, я скачиваю зип, закрываю и отключаю попап. Как-то так ))

Comment: Вот чтоб остановить этот попап я хочу отловить событие закрытия окна скачивания файлов..

Comment: @РоманТимохов А можете посмотреть, 1. Popup занимает всю ширину экрана в элементах?. 2. Посмотрите `id` или класс этого окна popup в консоли. Можно таким образом попробовать отловить его.

Comment: Этот плагин написан на `JQuery` у него есть два метода `$.preloader.start()` и  `$.preloader.stop()`. Первый его запускает, встраивая в DOM(в тег `<body>`) следующий элемент  `<div class="jquery-preloader" style="position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; z-index: 9999; background-image: url(&quot;/img/sprites.32.png&quot;); width: 32px; height: 32px; margin-left: -16px; margin-top: -16px; background-position: -64px 0px;"></div>`ну и скрипт там меняет позишины картики(спрайт) создавая эфект вращения. Ну и в принципе все..

Comment: Мне нужно его выключить `$.preloader.stop()` когда я нажму одну из кнопок(сохранить или отмена) по сути при закрытии окна..

Comment: @РоманТимохов Вам надо просто закрыть это окно? Тогда можно отслеживать фокус на этом поле.